# PHP failed to return animated gif directly as image

Tags: php, gif, animated-gif

I have a script that generate an animated gif. It once work fine but all of a sudden after some file transfer and git push/pull, the script is not functioning!

The problem is weird.

The following line is used to return the generated gif.

```
header('Content-type:image/gif');
echo $this->image;
```

Standard flow but the image is not displayed correctly, with code 200 when I check the header in chrome developer tool.

I once thought there was some problem with the code, but when I double check by returning normal html like this:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/*;base64,'.base64_encode($this->image).'" />';
```

The image shows up correctly.

Any idea what's the possible reason behind?

Comment: Take care that you not suffer from some caching issue. Clear you browsers cache or make a deep reload.

Comment: I have done that many times. (shift-reload, right?) I even opened firefox to make sure the result is not cached.

Comment: Hm, can't say more, since we did not post the code... Make sure the image payload really gets send inside your browsers development console (it should offer a preview of the gif in there), especially make sure that nothing else is sent by accident.